How to change child background image by the parent tag?
I can't access the child (div) to change the background image. I want to change it by it's parent. How?
<section class="l-section wpb_row frenach-header">
<div class="l-section-img" role="img" data-img-width="1587" data-img-height="700" style="background-image: url(https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2024/03/french-header.webp);"></div>
</section>

How can I access div tag through its parent (section) to change the background image?
I want to change the image by CSS only, not JS
Due to some reason, I can't call div directly, only have access to it's parent (section)

Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

In your code, an url is provided for the image. Do you want to change it via javascript ?

I am not sure if I understood your question correctly.
Solution #1:


How can I access div tag through its parent (section) to change the background image?

Have you tried variables? something like that:
.parent {
  --image-from-parent: url("some-url");
  ...
}

.child {
  background-image: var(--image-from-parent);
  ...
}

Solution #2:

You can use selectors:
.parent > div {
  background-image: url("some-url");
}


You can use querySelector. The following query search for a div inside section that has a attribute named 'role', which is set to 'img' and returns the first one. Then you can access the background image URL though .style.


const el = document.querySelector('section div[role="img"]').style.backgroundImage;                                           
console.log(el);
<section class="l-section wpb_row frenach-header">
<div class="l-section-img" role="img" data-img-width="1587" data-img-height="700" style="background-image: url(https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2024/03/french-header.webp);"></div>
</section>




No, not JS, only CSS

You would need to create a certain CSS snippet to create a hierarchy of parent to child properly.
See this example for reference:


.l-section .l-section-img {
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/1587/1587");
  width: 1587px;
  height: 700px;
}
<section class="l-section wpb_row frenach-header">
  <div class="l-section-img" role="img" data-img-width="1587" data-img-height="700"></div>
</section>



Here, the format of hierarchy is — .[parent class] [child class]
